# C# Making private instance variable accesable (jagged array)

Tags: c#

In a attempt to put some more oop in a program i am looking to make a private instance variable in one class (object) accesable to a class.

private byte [][] J;

All those code refers to this jagged array with this.
Now in the other class i putted all the for loops along with the consolewritlines to display the wanted results. Basicly it says "the name J does not exist in the current context"
But how exactly do i make this J accesable?

I have tried with get and set but i keep getting 'cannot convert to byte to byte[][]'

Also what kind of cyntax would i need with get and set?

Something along like this? Or would i need several more steps? :

```
public Byte JArray
get { return J; }  //can converrt to byte here
set { J = value; } //cannnot convert to byte here
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to expose a variable via a property, the type of the property has to be the same as the type of the variable (or compatible):

```
public byte[][] JArray
{
    get { return J; }
    set { J = value; }
}
```

However, you probably don't really need the setter - unless you actually want callers to be able to change J to refer to a different jagged array. Just with a getter they can still change values *within* the array, but they can't change the variable itself.

Even with this though, callers could still change the contents of the "outer" array, changing a whole "column" at a time:

```
foo.JArray[10] = new byte[10];
```

An alternative is to add an indexer to your class:

```
public byte this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return J[x][y]; }
    set { J[x][y] = value; }
}
```

This will only let callers access the actual elements, hiding the fact that it's backed by an array.

Exposing an array directly is generally a bad idea - indeed, leading minds [consider arrays to be somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input.  
DDo you mean something like this?            public byte JArray
        {
            get { return Convert.ToByte(J); }

        }/*Jagged*/

Although i cannot acces it from the other class.

Comment: @Chris: You're overcomplicating the issue. *If* you wish to expose the array, you have to expose it using the syntax in Jon's first sample. As he points out, though, you likely don't want a setter, and you even *more* likely don't want to expose the array at all.

Comment: +1, I was just about to write about making an indexer instead.

Comment: I was going to add an answer but Jon has given (from what I can tell) the correct answer already.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the situation correctly, the problem is that your types are mismatched.

Since the variable's type is `byte[][]` (i.e., an array of arrays of bytes) your property's return type needs to be `byte[][]`. Currently it's `Byte`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the types of your private variable and the public property are not the same. Try this:

```
public byte[][] JArray
{
    get { return J; }
    set { J = value; }
}
```

Or even shorter using automatic properties:

```
public byte[][] JArray { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

if J is of type byte[][], the associate property should also be of type byte[][].